Unable install python-ldap in python 2.7.9 on windows 11
I cannot install the required package because it needs Visual Studio C++ 9.0, which is no longer supported. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade my Python version because I need it for Odoo 8 development. Here is the error message I encountered in my terminal:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python27\python2.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\baash\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-build-tjzudv\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\baash\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-build-tjzudv\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\baash\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-kndz1b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python27\Include\python-ldap'
         cwd: c:\users\baash\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-tjzudv\
    Complete output (71 lines):
    defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
    extra_compile_args:
    extra_objects:
    include_dirs: /usr/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/local/include /usr/local/include/sasl
    library_dirs: /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
    libs: ldap_r
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\dsml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no files found matching 'Modules\LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building '_ldap' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python2.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\baash\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-build-tjzudv\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\baash\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-build-tjzudv\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\baash\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-kndz1b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python27\Include\python-ldap' Check the logs for full command output.

I have already tried downloading vcpython2.7 but it didn't work. How can I resolve this issue without upgrading my Python version? I need this setup for Odoo 8 development.

maybe Visual Studio C++ 9.0 is not supported but sometimes you may find it in some other places (or on Archive.org) and it may need to ask Google for this. OR maybe it needs only program Make (to run script Makefile) from any version.

I found one link to VC for Python 2.7 but on Torrent https://archive.org/details/VC-Py27 . I have no problem to download this torrent but I use Linux so I can't test it. And I don't know if it safe.
